# ANDROID sqlite can not retrieve

Tags: android, sqlite

When i do seperate queries like this, i can get what query says. I want to retrieve events according to type and time,i want events not ended, and today but not started so, that is query maker code:

```
 db = this.getWritableDatabase();


        if(cursor.moveToFirst()==false){
            Log.e(TAG,"null");
            return null;
        }//bulamadıysa hic null dondruyor
     //   Log.e(TAG,"cursor: "+cursor.getColumnNames());
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Event event = new Event();
                // event.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                event.setName(cursor.getString(1));

                event.setDescription(cursor.getString(7));
                event.setLink(cursor.getString(4));
                event.setLocation(cursor.getString(2));
                event.setType(cursor.getString(3));
                event.setStartDate(cursor.getString(5));
                event.setEndDate(cursor.getString(6));

                // to show user if correct, write screen
                eventList.add(event);
               event.writeSc(event);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
        return eventList;
    }
```

First i make seperate, this is working:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_EVENTS+
            " WHERE ("

           + KEY_START_TIME+" <= '"+formatter.format(currentDate.getTime())+"'"
            +" AND "
            + KEY_END_TIME+   " >= '"+formatter.format(currentDate.getTime())+"') "+

            " OR ("+KEY_END_TIME + " BETWEEN '"+formatter.format(currentDate.getTime())+"' " +
            "AND '"+formatter.format(currentDate.getTime()).substring(0,10)+ " 23:59')" +

     //   " AND "+
      //KEY_TYPE+" = \""+type_+"\""
        " ORDER BY "+ KEY_START_TIME +" ASC";
```

Also this is working

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_EVENTS+
            " WHERE "

     //      + KEY_START_TIME+" <= //'"+formatter.format(currentDate.getTime())+"'"
         //   +" AND "
           // + KEY_END_TIME+   " >= //'"+formatter.format(currentDate.getTime())+"') "+

         //   " OR ("+KEY_END_TIME + " BETWEEN //'"+formatter.format(currentDate.getTime())+"' " +
   //         "AND //'"+formatter.format(currentDate.getTime()).substring(0,10)+ " 23:59')" +

  //   //   " AND "+
     KEY_TYPE+" = \""+type_+"\""
        " ORDER BY "+ KEY_START_TIME +" ASC";
```

But when i merge them, it doesnot work. It was working but i dont know whathappened. And i know, they are sometting common, they have some events togeteher but retrieves all kind of events when i make together

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_EVENTS+
            " WHERE ("

           + KEY_START_TIME+" <= '"+formatter.format(currentDate.getTime())+"'"
            +" AND "
            + KEY_END_TIME+   " >= '"+formatter.format(currentDate.getTime())+"') "+

            " OR ("+KEY_END_TIME + " BETWEEN '"+formatter.format(currentDate.getTime())+"' " +
            "AND '"+formatter.format(currentDate.getTime()).substring(0,10)+ " 23:59')" +

        " AND "+
      KEY_TYPE+" = \""+type_+"\""
        " ORDER BY "+ KEY_START_TIME +" ASC";
```

I can paste wrong but they are correct, studio doesnot give errors. Please help. ıicant see it for days, i am really nervous. It must be maybe small thing but i am not able to see it no more.

Comment: Try with "OR" instead of "AND"..

Answer (score 0):

It is really stupid. I collected all and together and put common query to both condition of or and it worked:

```
 String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_EVENTS+
            " WHERE ("

           + KEY_START_TIME+" <= '"+formatter.format(currentDate.getTime())+"'"
            +" AND "
            + KEY_END_TIME+   " >= '"+formatter.format(currentDate.getTime())+"' "+" AND "+KEY_TYPE+" = \""+type_+"\")"+

            " OR ("+KEY_END_TIME + " BETWEEN '"+formatter.format(currentDate.getTime())+"' " +
            "AND '"+formatter.format(currentDate.getTime()).substring(0,10)+ " 23:59'" +" AND "+KEY_TYPE+" = \""+type_+"\")"


       + " ORDER BY "+ KEY_START_TIME +" ASC";
```

thank you